# How to share Java code between Android and JVM targets (with Kotlin Multiplatform)?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

I am trying to share Java code between Android and JVM targets using Kotlin Multiplatform feature (sample project: https://github.com/dmitrykolesnikovich/accessJavaCode-issue)

Simply saying, ":library1" and ":library2" both are Kotlin multiplatform libraries targeting JVM and Android. ":library2" depends on ":library1".  They both uses Kotlin and Java. ":library2" is intended to be dependency of 1) Android application and 2) desktop (JavaFX) application. That's why 1) AAR artifact and 2) JAR artifact both are needed (?) - so I use 1) Android target and 2) JVM target for both ":library1" and ":library2".

The problem is that, when I have Java code in ":library1"

```java
public class JavaCode {} // JavaCode.java
```

And Kotlin code in ":library2" that depends on ":library1"

```
class AccessJavaCode : JavaCode() // AccessJavaCode.kt
```

Android target is OK with recognizing Java but JVM target is not:

```
> Task :library2:compileKotlinJvm FAILED
e: AccessJavaCode.kt: (3, 38): Unresolved reference: JavaCode
```

In gradle config I define two plugins: `kotlin-multiplatform` and `com.android.library`:

```
apply plugin: "kotlin-multiplatform"
apply plugin: "com.android.library"

kotlin {
    targets {
        jvm()
        android()
    }
    sourceSets {
        jvmMain {
            dependencies {
                api kotlin("stdlib-common")
                api kotlin("stdlib-jdk8")            
            }
        }
        androidMain {
            dependsOn jvmMain
        }
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    sourceSets {
        main {
            java.srcDirs += "src/jvmMain/kotlin" // Android target recognizes Java with this
            manifest.srcFile "src/androidMain/AndroidManifest.xml"
        }
    }
}
```

I am pretty sure it’s something simple with my gradle file. Many thanks for your help guys.

Comment: Library 1 is a plain java and library 2 is android library?

Comment: ":library1" and ":library2" both are Kotlin multiplatform libraries targeting JVM and Android. They both uses Kotlin and Java. ":library2" is intended to be dependency of 1) Android application and 2) desktop (JavaFX) application. That's why 1) AAR artifact and 2) JAR artifact both are needed (?) - so I use 1) Android target and 2) JVM target for both ":library1" and ":library2".

Comment: Ok got that, but my question is does the libraries using android or java fx frameworks or they just ding standard java code operations .do you intend that one of the libraries will create Fragment or something like that ?

Comment: standard java code only, no specificity

Comment: I cloned you project but I have a question if those libraries are not dependent on Android framework, why do you have 'AndroidManifest.xml' and android targets in your grade build files?

Comment: Another question is what command did you run that caused the error ? did you use IDE or command line ?

Comment: - `gradlew build` caused an error.

Comment: I mean, usage of Android framework is not requirement for my use case. But is should be possible to do so. That's why AndroidManifest is present to cover general case.

Comment: That was my first question too. If either library1 or library2 has any Android references it will not work on JavaFX desktop.

Comment: They have android dependencies in androidMain source set, not in jvmMain source set.

Comment: I have tried the project in my computer and I saw that Library2 can receive dependencies from Library1, but only kaitlin classes, it cannot receive java class dependency, and I saw that the .kt files are compiled to a file but the .java aren't .

Comment: I didn't found a solution thought

Comment: Ok. Thanks for try and response. No one can answer https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/how-to-share-java-code-between-android-and-jvm-targets

Comment: may this help: https://blog.gradle.org/alignment-with-gradle-module-metadata

Comment: @DmitryKolesnikovich Not sure if this could help: https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/multi-platform-project-with-a-jvm-common-target/12032

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## ~~~~ EDIT ~~~~

Another workaround the issue without losing the ability to generate an android archive `.aar` for the `library1` would be to make a new version of this same library depending on precompiled artefacts of a splitted version of the original `library1`.

So you would end up with a multi-module gradle project, something like this:

- library1-jvm with java plugin enabled
- library1-android with android plugin enabled
- library1 which will depends on prebuilt library1-jvm.jar and library1-android.aar

You could use whatever you prefer to publish those artefacts, but a `local maven repo` should work just fine!

That would mean replacing:

```
kotlin {
    targets {
        jvm()
        android()
    }
    sourceSets {
        jvmMain {
            dependencies {
                 api kotlin("stdlib-common")
                 api kotlin("stdlib-jdk8")
            }
        }
        androidMain {
            dependsOn jvmMain
        }
    }
}
```

with:

```
kotlin {
    targets {
        jvm()
        android()
    }
    sourceSets {
        jvmMain {
            dependencies {
                api kotlin("stdlib-common")
                api kotlin("stdlib-jdk8")
                api "com.company:library-jvm:1.0.0" 
            }
        }
        androidMain {
            dependsOn jvmMain
            dependencies {
                api "com.company:library-android:1.0.0"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That way, you don't need the java plugin at all in the final `library1`, because all the java code will already be built in a separate step.

Hence `library1` could keep both the `JVM` and `Android` targets

## ~~~~~~~~~~~~~

In order to fix your issue, you need to:

- Split your build.gradle configuration in order to have one config per library, this will be needed because you cannot enable the java plugin and the android at the same time for the same Gradle project, or you will end up with the following `Error: The 'java' plugin has been applied, but it is not compatible with the Android plugins`
- Enable the java plugin in your `library1` project if you want your JVM target to recognize your Java source files.
- The Java source files need to be placed in the sibling directories `java` of the `kotlin` source roots.

[image: java source roots]

More infos: Kotlin docs for [java-support-in-jvm-targets](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/building-mpp-with-gradle.html#java-support-in-jvm-targets)

I also created a [pull request](https://github.com/dmitrykolesnikovich/accessJavaCode-issue/pull/1) solving your issue.

The downside of this approach is that you will not be able to generate an android archive `.aar`  for the `library1`, but I guess using the java archive `.jar` in your android project should not be a problem at all.

***library1/build.gradle:***

```
apply plugin: "kotlin-multiplatform"

kotlin {
    jvm {
        withJava()
    }

    sourceSets {
        jvmMain {
            dependencies {
                api kotlin("stdlib-common")
                api kotlin("stdlib-jdk8")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

***library2/build.gradle:***

```
apply plugin: "kotlin-multiplatform"
apply plugin: "com.android.library"

kotlin{
    jvm()
    android()

    sourceSets {
        jvmMain.dependencies {
            api project(":library1")
        }
        androidMain {
            dependsOn jvmMain
        }
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    sourceSets {
        main {
             java.srcDirs += "src/jvmMain/kotlin"
             manifest.srcFile "src/androidMain/AndroidManifest.xml"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But what if ":library1" has to have android specific classes? Is there some way to deal with that? (Your solution is what I considered myself but that was not ideal for me, so I decided to ask on SO)

Comment: I don't see how you can have `library1` contain some android specific code, and expect the exported `.jar` to run on any JVM.
It is a broken architecture...

Comment: I have android specific code in `androidMain` source set. That's how exported `.jar` will not have any android specific code.

Comment: Ok I understand, but unfortunately, as of now `kotlin 1.3.61`, there is no way to have the `jvm withJava` and the `android` target in the same `kotlin-multiplatform` project. 
You will end up with the `Error: The 'java' plugin has been applied, but it is not compatible with the Android plugins`

Comment: I consider `java` and `android` plugins can not work together by design regardless of `kotlin-multiplatform` current state. So, it's one who utilizes those plugins is responsible to find the way to use them together not JetBrains guys who improve `kotlin-multiplatform`

Comment: Probably, but still this is how it is documented in the kotlin docs: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/building-mpp-with-gradle.html#java-support-in-jvm-targets

Comment: The question is how to find workaround to make my thing work.

Comment: Sorry but it wasn't really clear to me that you were aware of the current limitation, and I proposed a solution to your problem.
Even if you have android source code in `library1` this solution should work, the only downside is that you cannot have android resources packaged in a `jar` that's all.
And obviously you should not try to call any android api in a non-android target

Comment: This "the only downside" makes your solution incomplete and thus inappropriate. I will mark your answer as correct though. Because SO is about correct answers not useful ones.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205249/discussion-between-gomino-and-dmitry-kolesnikovich).